# I get this error in React - TypeError: Cannot create property 'completed' on boolean 'true'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, state

I'm building a "todo" app for practicing & learning React basics. I have an array of objects from a file called `TodosStores.js` which I passed down as `props` to the `TodoList` component like so:

```js
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import TodosStores from './stores/TodosStore';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TodoList todos={TodosStores} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Now, I'm trying trying to toggle the property value of the current `todo.completed` to `true` & `false` so I can remove/add the `todo-item-completed` class. However, I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot create property 'completed' on boolean 'true'`. I am seeking some explanation of what I'm doing wrong here. I come from Vue background so probably there's another way of changing the `state` in React.

This is my component's code snippet:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './TodoListStyles.css'

class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    
    this.state = { todos: this.props.todos }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(item) {
    return item.completed = !item.completed
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <ul className='todo-list'>
        { 
          this.props.todos.map(
            todo => 
            <React.Fragment key={todo.id}>
              <li className={`todo-item ${todo.completed ? 'todo-item-completed' : ''}`}>{ todo.title }</li>
              <input type='checkbox' onChange={this.handleChange(todo.completed)} checked={todo.completed} />
            </React.Fragment>
          ) 
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

export default TodoList;
```

PS: I'm using React Class Components because I want to contribute to an open-source project which uses class components. I might try refactoring later to hooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting error `TypeError: Cannot create property 'completed' on boolean 'true'` is because you are passing boolean value to `handleChange` in `onChange={this.handleChange(todo.completed)}` and in the function you are creating/mutating `item.completed`.
It can not create property `completed` on `true` or `false` basically.

Comment: Tks for the reply. I see, I changed the `param` to `todo` instead of `todo.completed` like so: `<input type='checkbox' onChange={this.handleChange(todo)} checked={todo.completed} />`. But I'm getting a new error: `Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `boolean` type.`

Comment: You will have to use onChange={() => this.handleChange(todo)}

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks! Can you explain to me why it doesn't work with `onChange={this.handleChange(todo)}`, please? I'm building this project to learn/getting comfortable with React so I would like to know more :)

Comment: With this.handleChange(todo) you are calling/invoking the function directly whereas with () => this.handleChange(todo) you are creating an anonymous function, calling the handleChange function and then passing a custom parameter to it. onChange={this.handleChange} would have also worked if <input /> is another component, since then you are passing a reference to this function as a prop and then inside <input /> you could have called the function as this.props.handleOnchange(todo)